# Maximizing Profit with two limited products

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The Problem

A company uses two intermediate products to produce their end product. The profit when using x (in thousands) of product 1, and z (in hundreds) of product 2 is known to be

P = (x − 0.5)(z − 1)(11 − 2x − z) + 500

Both products are limited, we have x ≤ 6 and z ≤ 10.

I am trying to find out which combination of x and z will create the Maximum Profit.

Currently I have determined the first derivative as (z-1)(-4x-z+12)

I am unsure how to progress from here with two variables as well as the limit imposed on both variables. Does anyone know the procedure for this type of Profit Maximization Question?

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $f(x,z) = (x-0.5)(z-1)(11-2x-z)$ the relative minimum/maximum/saddle points obey the condition

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 4x (1-z)+z (13 -z)-12 = 0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x (x+z-6.5)-0.5 z+3 = 0
$$

Those solutions are shown in red, over the level contour map for $f(x,z)$. Now I leave to you the corresponding qualification  as relative minimum/maximum/saddle points.

[image]